# Call Angular2 functions in series, one after the other

Tags: javascript, function, angular, typescript

I have a service in an Angular2 project that takes some parameters and returns a value list to populate drop down menus on a form. When the form component initializes, I need to call the same service multiple times with different parameters to define a number of different dropdown menus, however if I call them all, the last one called clobbers the previous ones, presumably because the subsequent calls are overriding or cancelling the previous fetches.

I've split each of the calls into their own function, but I need a way to call each function in series so that the second doesn't get called until after the first completes. Each function works on its own, however if I call more than one, only the last one succeeds, and the first fail with errors (as the service itself terminates the current fetch when its called with new parameters before finishing).

```
 this.fetchValueListOne();
 this.fetchValueListTwo();
 this.fetchValueListThree();
```

I was trying to make this work with promises, but wound up in scoping hell pretty quickly with having to pass the services I wanted to access into the functions and then not being able to get the resulting data back out again - each service call takes three parameters and then sets a specific this.valueList[] variable defined in the component and used on the form.

I also tried creating a list of the functions as variables and then iterating over them, however I ran into the same scoping issues as with promises.

The service returns an Observable, the functions subscribe to that Observable, retrieve the data and assign it to a array variable in the component that a dropdown value list is bound to.

The functions look like this:

```
fetchValueListOne() {
      this.dataSvc.getValueList('Val-List-One', this.stateSvc.currentContext, this.stateSvc.currentLanguageCode)
          .map(response => response.json())
          .subscribe(
          data => {
              this.valListOne = data;
          },
          err => console.log('Error', err),
          () => {
              console.log('this.valListOne', this.valListOne);
          }
          );
  }
```

Comment: The three functions return promises or observables?

Comment: The service returns an Observables, the functions subscribe to the Observable, retrieve the data and assign it to a specific variable in the component.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call the functions when you received the data. Such as:

```
    this.fetchValueListOne().subscribe((firstData) => {
            this.fetchValueListTwo(firstData);
            // Do something with firstData
        }
    );

    this.fetchValueListTwo().subscribe((secondData) => {
            this.fetchValueListThree(secondData);
            // Do something with secondData
        }
    );

    this.fetchValueListThree().subscribe((thirdData) => {
            // Do something with thirdData
        }
    );
```

And declare these functions as `Observable`, such as:

```
public fetchValueListOne(): Observable<any> { // Get firstData }
public fetchValueListTwo(): Observable<any> { // Get secondData}
public fetchValueListThree(): Observable<any> { // Get thirdData}
```

This way you will be certain that when you call a function you have the data from the previous one.

Answer (score 3):

SrAxi pointed me in the right direction, and ultimately I solved the problem as follows where Promises turned out to be the best solution, specifically the Promise / .then mechanism solved the problem nicely.

```
  fetchValueList(listCode): Promise<any> {
      return this.dataSvc.getValueList(listCode, this.stateSvc.currentContext, this.stateSvc.currentLanguageCode)
          .map(response => response.json())
          .toPromise();
  }

  initializeDropDowns() {
      this.fetchValueList('First-Val-List')
          .then(data => {
              this.firstValList = data;
              return this.fetchValueList('Second-Val-List')
          }).then(data => {
              this.secondValList = data;
              return this.fetchValueList('Third-Val-List')
          }).then(data => {
              this.thirdValList = data;
          })  }
```

I defined the functions in the component, and then called initializeDropDowns() in ngOnInit.

The fetchValueList function returns a Promise, so the first call passes the first listCode and when the Promise resolves, the return value is in the data variable in the .then block where we can assign it to the this.firstValList variable. As the function has returned data, we know the service has finished and it's safe to call again with the second listCode, the return value is in the data variable in the next .then block and we assign it to the this.secondValList variable.

We can chain this as many times as required to populate all the variables, and on the last code block we simply omit the return statement and the block terminates.

This is a very specific use case where we have a single service that needs to be called multiple times as the component initializes, and where the service has to complete its fetch and return a value before it can be called again, but in this case, the Promise / .then method was ideal.

Comment: I'm glad I was useful! Have a nice day! ;)